# How to get Content-Disposition contents from WSO2 6.2 ESB REST API or Custom Mediator

Tags: wso2, esb, mediator

What I'm trying to do is to get the file name includes extension as well. The client can post to the rest api with any type of file such as (text, image, doc, and etc.).

I have been trying to figure out this for several of days now but unfortunately have not had any luck yet.

Can someone help me get out of this?

I have tried to get from the properties context, but got nothing

ESB code:

```
    <api context="/esb" name="OCR" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <resource methods="POST" uri-template="/upload">
        <inSequence>
            <property name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="multipart/form-data"/>
            <property name="ContentType" value="multipart/form-data" scope="axis2"/>
            <property expression="$body//file" name="fileVar" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <log level="custom">
                <property name="CONTENT_DISPOSITION_1" expression="get-property('CONTENT_DISPOSITION')"/>
                <property name="CONTENT_DISPOSITION_2" expression="get-property('TRANSPORT_HEADERS')"/>
            </log>
            <class name="com.example.GetContentDisposition"/>
            <respond/>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence/>
        <faultSequence/>
    </resource>
</api>
```

Output:

CONTENT_DISPOSITION_1 = null and CONTENT_DISPOSITION_2 = null

I have tried with the custom mediator

custom mediator code:

```
public boolean mediate(MessageContext context) {
    //Accessing Transport Headers
    System.out.println("------Transport Headers-------");
    Map<String,Object> mapTransportProperties = (Map<String, Object>) ((Axis2MessageContext)context).getAxis2MessageContext().getProperty("TRANSPORT_HEADERS");
    for (Map.Entry entry : mapTransportProperties.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println("TRANS:" +entry.getKey() + ", " + entry.getValue());
    }
    return true;
}
```

Output:

------Transport Headers-------

TRANS:Accept, */* 
TRANS:Accept-Encoding, gzip, deflate 
TRANS:Cache-Control, no-cache 
TRANS:Connection, keep-alive 
TRANS:Content-Length, 233 
TRANS:Content-Type, multipart/form-data 
TRANS:Host, localhost:8280 
TRANS:Postman-Token, e1261dad-947b-4ece-921b-bbe81d232eb6 
TRANS:User-Agent, PostmanRuntime/7.17.1

It doesn't have Content Disposition in the Headers

In POSTMAN results I can see the content disposition.

[image]

Comment: Hi @user1998820,
Did you find solutions for this? i am also trying to fetch attachment name comes from postman. please look below. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64347153/attachment-handling-through-wso2-ei-6-1-1-in-api

Answer (score 0):

Can you enable wire logs to check if the header is passed to the ESB server

Answer (score 0):

1. this is because you are using

multipart/form-data (there is a bug with this)
change it to:

application/x-www-form-urlencoded

You will see in logs:

```
[2020-08-07 12:11:36,865] [EI-Core] DEBUG - headers http-incoming-15 << HTTP/1.1 200 OK
[2020-08-07 12:11:36,865] [EI-Core] DEBUG - headers http-incoming-15 << Cache-Control: no-cache
[2020-08-07 12:11:36,866] [EI-Core] DEBUG - headers http-incoming-15 << Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="IVT000763184.pdf"
[2020-08-07 12:11:36,866] [EI-Core] DEBUG - headers http-incoming-15 << Content-Type: application/text
[2020-08-07 12:11:36,866] [EI-Core] DEBUG - headers http-incoming-15 << Date: Fri, 07 Aug 2020 12:11:36 GMT
[2020-08-07 12:11:36,867] [EI-Core] DEBUG - headers http-incoming-15 << Transfer-Encoding: chunked
[2020-08-07 12:11:36,867] [EI-Core] DEBUG - headers http-incoming-15 << Connection: keep-alive
```

2. You don't need to create mediator go get header response. You can get it by change:
   "org.apache.synapse.transport.http.headers"    to    DEBUG in WSO2 configuration.
3. Ad 2) Maybe you have too many Message Buider/Formatter enabled.

   ```
    <!--                Message Formatter                   -->
    <!-- ================================================= -->
    <messageFormatters>
        <messageFormatter contentType="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
                          class="org.apache.synapse.commons.formatters.XFormURLEncodedFormatter"/>
        <messageFormatter contentType="multipart/form-data"
                          class="org.apache.axis2.transport.http.MultipartFormDataFormatter"/>
        <messageFormatter contentType="application/xml"
                          class="org.apache.axis2.transport.http.ApplicationXMLFormatter"/>
        <messageFormatter contentType="text/xml"
                          class="org.apache.axis2.transport.http.SOAPMessageFormatter"/>
        <messageFormatter contentType="application/soap+xml"
                          class="org.apache.axis2.transport.http.SOAPMessageFormatter"/>
        <messageFormatter contentType="text/plain"
                          class="org.apache.axis2.format.PlainTextFormatter"/>
        <messageFormatter contentType="application/octet-stream"
                          class="org.wso2.carbon.relay.ExpandingMessageFormatter"/>
        <messageFormatter contentType="application/pdf"
                          class="org.wso2.carbon.relay.ExpandingMessageFormatter"/>
        <messageFormatter contentType="application/json"
                          class="org.wso2.carbon.integrator.core.json.JsonStreamFormatter"/>
        <messageFormatter contentType="text/html"
                        class="org.wso2.carbon.relay.ExpandingMessageFormatter"/>
        <messageFormatter contentType="application/file"
                         class="org.wso2.carbon.relay.ExpandingMessageFormatter"/>
    </messageFormatters>

    <!-- ================================================= -->
    <!--                Message Builders                   -->
    <!-- ================================================= -->

    <messageBuilders>
        <messageBuilder contentType="application/xml"
                        class="org.apache.axis2.builder.ApplicationXMLBuilder"/>
        <messageBuilder contentType="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
                        class="org.apache.synapse.commons.builders.XFormURLEncodedBuilder"/>
        <messageBuilder contentType="multipart/form-data"
                        class="org.apache.axis2.builder.MultipartFormDataBuilder"/>
        <messageBuilder contentType="text/plain"
                        class="org.apache.axis2.format.PlainTextBuilder"/>
        <messageBuilder contentType="application/octet-stream"
                        class="org.wso2.carbon.relay.BinaryRelayBuilder"/>
        <messageBuilder contentType="text/html"
                        class="org.wso2.carbon.relay.BinaryRelayBuilder"/>
        <messageBuilder contentType="application/json"
                        class="org.wso2.carbon.integrator.core.json.JsonStreamBuilder"/>
        <messageBuilder contentType="application/pdf" 
                        class="org.wso2.carbon.relay.BinaryRelayBuilder"/>
        <messageBuilder contentType="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
                        class="org.wso2.carbon.relay.BinaryRelayBuilder"/>
        <messageBuilder contentType="multipart/form-data"
                        class="org.wso2.carbon.relay.BinaryRelayBuilder"/>
        <messageBuilder contentType="application/file"
                        class="org.apache.axis2.format.BinaryBuilder"/>
    </messageBuilders>
   ```
4. This is my call that works

`<property name="messageType" value="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"  scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>`

`<property name="DISABLE_CHUNKING" value="false" scope="axis2"/>`

`<call>`

`<endpoint>`

`<http method="POST" uri-template="https://www.proceedo.net/suppliercenter/common/orderexport.do"/>`

`</endpoint>`

`</call>`

`<respond/>`

after that file is downloaded via wget or browser like Chrone

5. **Do you solve this problem?** I don't know how to save this file to a server. When I open this API URL in browser it automatically download it. But I don't know how to save it via WSO2 on server.

Comment: Hi @user3345547,
how can we fetch attachment/file name from request comes from postman?i am also trying similar kind of operation. please look into below https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64347153/attachment-handling-through-wso2-ei-6-1-1-in-api